# Adding, then referencing, Django Form Widgets in HTML templates

Tags: jquery, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have the following widgets in my form class;

```
class InputParametersForm(forms.Form):

sqlConnection = SQLSeverConnection('MSSQLServerDataSource','default_user','password123!','HD')
tableChoices = sqlConnection.getTableNames()

TableName = forms.Select(widget=forms.SelectMultiple,
                                 choices=tableChoices)

ColumnName = forms.Select(widget=forms.SelectMultiple)

StartDateTime = forms.DateTimeInput(widget=forms.DateTimeInput)
EndDateTime = forms.DateTimeInput(widget=forms.DateTimeInput)

class Meta:
    model = SelectionHistory
    fields = ("TableName","ColumnName","StartDateTime","EndDateTime")
```

My current template is;

```
 <script>
        $('#id_tables').change(function()
        {
            tableSelectionChanged();
        })

        function tableSelectionChanged()
        {
            var selected_table = $('#id_tables').selectedIndex;
            $.get('/historicaldata/input_parameters/', {selected_table : selected_table}, function(data){
            $('#id_columns').val(data);
            });
        }


    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>What would you like to see?</h1>

    <form id="input_parameters" method="post" action="#">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <select name="tables" id="id_tables" size="5">
            {% for table in form.tableChoices %}
                <option value="{{table.id}}">{{table}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>

        <select name="columns" id="id_columns" size="5">
            {% for column in form.columnChoices %}
                <option value="{{column.id}}">{{column}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>

        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>

</body>
```

I'd like to add the widgets defined in the form as opposed to the select type objects I've added in the template. How do I do this in terms of syntax? And then how would I access the widgets event handlers to replicate the ajax/jquery I have already?

From what I've searched for thus far on the topic I've struggled to find anything specific.

If you have the time I'd really appreciate an example.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is. Why not just `{{ form.TableName }}` etc?

Comment: How would I add the <options> to it and reference it in my jquery event handlers etc - currently a django noob

Comment: You provide the options in the Django form definition, as you've done with TableName (but not ColumnName). I don't understand your question about jQuery though: the template outputs normal HTML, you can reference them in exactly the same way as any other element.

Comment: if in my template i rendered my form (form.as_p) how would i use the widgets in my form in the above jquery? currently i have $('#id_tables').change(function() what would I replace #id_tables with if were to reference the tables widget from the form?

Comment: I don't recommend using `form.as_p`, but specifying the fields individually with `{{ form.TableName }}`, as I stated above. But I still don't understand your question. The way Django creates ID elements [is fully documented and configurable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/api/#configuring-form-elements-html-id-attributes-and-label-tags), but even if it wasn't, couldn't you simply try it and inspect the results in the browser dev tools?

Comment: ok so if i set auto_id = true in the widget definition then i could access it using, in the case of TableName, as id_TableName so my jquery above would be $('#id_TableName').change(function()...  ?

Answer (score 0):

You should render the form as suggested by django rather than building the HTML as you have done.

Refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates) document for detail explanation.

As summary, you can render the form using `{{form`}} or `{{form.as_p}}` or `{{form.as_table}}` etc.

Also you can render individual field with

```
{%for field in form %}
    {{field}}
{%endfor%}
```

and other variants.

Comment: Yeh I'm aware of this, what I can't understand is how to use the widgets in jquerys if i do this?

Comment: @MarkCorrigan, Your question is not clear then. Code generated by widget is html, that you can refer in js as with other html elements.

Comment: apoligies for the lack of clarity, but how would i reference it? what would the id tag of the form widget be? i haven't supplied it with any..

Comment: must i give the widget an id value in the form.py?

Comment: @MarkCorrigan, Not sure you can give id to a field widget. But you can have divs over fields and provide ids there. Refer to the docs page which shows how you can render individual field in different ways and all other items related to it.